# Why do I get unexpected type when using None for Google BigQuery DB-API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, python-db-api

I'm trying to migrate data from a MySQL table to a BigQuery table using Python, but it gives me the following error when I try to insert a NULL value:

> google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi.exceptions.ProgrammingError: Encountered parameter None with value None of unexpected type.

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()  ##GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'api/google.json'
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import dbapi
import datetime

client = bigquery.Client()
connection = dbapi.Connection(client)

def write(query, data):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    connection.commit()
    return 'OK!'

data = (9, '857', '11013', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 28, 15, 33, 13), datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 28, 15, 33, 13))

query = """
INSERT INTO `<project>.<dataset>.tmp_accountContacts`
(
id,account,contact,jobTitle,createdTimestamp,updatedTimestamp)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);
"""

write(query, data)
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Welcome and great first question! Assuming the data type of `jobTitle` is `string` can you please try: `VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%(:string)s,%s,%s);` and let me know if that works?

Comment: That worked! Why is is this necessary with Bigquery and not with for example MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

The error (`unexpected type`) indicates that BigQuery DB-API can't detect the type for the parameter, since it's `None`.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/dbapi#providing-explicit-type-information) explain this:

> BigQuery requires type information for parameters. The BigQuery DB-API can usually determine parameter types for parameters based on provided values. Sometimes, however, **types can’t be determined (for example when None is passed)** or are determined incorrectly (for example when passing a floating-point value to a numeric column).

You need to explicitly specify the data type when you want to pass through `None`.

In your case, you need to specify that `jobTitle` is a `string` (and do the same for any other parameter that you could pass `None` through for).

```sql
INSERT INTO `<project>.<dataset>.tmp_accountContacts`
(id,account,contact,jobTitle,createdTimestamp,updatedTimestamp)
VALUES (%s,%s,%(:string)s,%s,%s,%s);
```

---

Technically, the library could just convert `None` to `NULL` in the final BigQuery SQL query so not sure why it doesn't, as BigQuery itself doesn't need to know the type when storing `NULL` ‍♂️

The docs saying:

> BigQuery requires type information for parameters

should probably say:

> BigQuery *DB-API* requires type information for parameters